# Insert into MySql failed

Tags: mysql, database

Hy everyone i have a problem when i try to insert something in database. The DB method is:

```
public static void insertInEntries(String NrDeOrdine, String NrDocument,String Data, String Emitent, String Continut, String Observatii)
            throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        try {
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Intrari " + "VALUES("
                    + NrDeOrdine + "," + NrDocument + "," + Data + ","
                    + Emitent + "," + Continut + "," + Observatii + ");");
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Eroare:" + e);
        }
    }
```

In fxml i have a button, which action this methon on click!

```
@FXML protected void eadaugareIn(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        DBConnection.connect();
        DBConnection.getConnection();
        try
        {
            DBConnection.insertInEntries(enrOrdInput.getText().toString(), enrDocInput.getText().toString(), edataInput.getText().toString(), eemitentInput.getText().toString(), econtinutTextArea.getText().toString(), eobsTextArea.getText().toString());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println("Eroare:" + e);
        }
    }
```

So everything i am putting in this field seems to get me the error if in the first textfield the text is " sa " i put into the textfields:

```
Eroare:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'sa' in 'field list'
```

How i could solve this? Thank you very much!

EDIT: I found the answer a few hours ago:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `intrari`(`NrDeOrdine`, `NrDocument`, `Data`, `Emitent`, `Continut`, `Observatii`) 
    VALUES("+ '"' + NrDeOrdine + '"' + "," + '"' + NrDocument + '"' + "," + '"' 
    + Data + '"' + "," + '"' + Emitent + '"' + "," + '"' + Continut + '"' + "," 
    + '"' + Observatii + '"' + ");");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add logging to your `insertInEntries` method:

```
System.out.println("INSERT INTO Intrari " + "VALUES("
                + NrDeOrdine + "," + NrDocument + "," + Data + ","
                + Emitent + "," + Continut + "," + Observatii + ");");
```

Most probably looking at the output will give you solution.

Comment: I added the answer at the bottom of the question! Thank for trying to help me, Sergey!